# Как передать функцию в качестве аргумента предварительно ее не создавая?

Tags: python

Есть класс Timer в который я сейчас отправляю функцию подобным образом:

```
t = Timer(3.0, self.clPC4),
def clPC4(self):
        ...
```

Каким образом можно передавать функцию в качестве аргумента не создавая ее, например в JavaScript я бы передал эту функцию например так:

```
timer(3.0, function() {
 ...
});
```

В Python есть нечто подобное?

Comment: Есть lambda-функции - используются они только если вызываемый код можно описать в одну строку. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
In [251]: def f(a, b, func):
     ...:     return func(a,b)
     ...:

In [252]: def my_mul(a,b):
     ...:     return a * b
     ...:

In [253]: f(3, 5, my_mul)
Out[253]: 15
```

---

```
In [254]: def my_sum(a,b):
     ...:     return a + b
     ...:

In [255]: f(3, 5, my_sum)
Out[255]: 8
```

Comment: Альтернатива второму варианту, используя lambda: `lambda a,b: a+b`

Comment: @floydya, да, можно воспользоваться lambda функцией, но я предпочитаю пользоваться ими только когда это необходимо ;-)